# jQuery | if the hash value of the url equal a matching anchor tag, then simulate a click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simulate a click on one of my tabs if the url matches the `href` value of an anchor tag.

This is what I have been trying so far:

```
if (window.location.hash.indexOf('!/') !== -1) {

    $('#nav li a').each(function(i) {

        if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#' + window.location.hash.substring(3)) !== -1)
            $(this).trigger('click');
    });
}
```

My `hash` looks like `!/something` and my `url` looks like `http://domain.com/#!/something`

So, I check to see if `!/` is in the URL, then I want to click on the link in my nav that has a matching `href` to `#something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.hash` return hash containing the `#` in some browser and in some don't so before comparing you should replace it with nothing. Try this.

```
if (window.location.hash.indexOf('!/') !== -1) {

    $('#nav li a').each(function(i) {

        if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#' + window.location.hash.replace('#', '').substring(3)) !== -1)
            $(this).trigger('click');
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but it doesn't seem to want to find the anchor with the matching href and trigger the click

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to search for what's after the hashbang..

Untested code:

```
if (window.location.hash.indexOf('!/') !== -1) {
    $('#nav li a[href$='+window.location.hash+']').click();
}
```

Edit: Based on the other answer, simply adding changing `href=` to `href$=` makes this cross-browser compatible.